# Send value from a file to another in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to reference a cell from one file into another and I need to do it from the first file.

Normally i would go on the "destination" file and insert something like '`[filename.xlsx]sheet'!$C$40` in the wanted cell, but in this case I would like to send the value/cell directly from the input file, something like "this value has to be sent to '`[filename.xlsx]sheet'!$C$40`".

Even better would be if I could choose where to copy the value/cell by indicating the coordinates of the destination cell using the names I assign to the first row cells and the first column cells (like " send this value to `[filename.xlsx]sheettextoffirstrawp textoffirstcolumn10` to send it to `filename.xlsx P10` cell)

Is there any macro (or something else) that already do something like this? If not, do you think it can be done?

Thanks for the help, if what I'm asking is not clear enough please let me know, I will try to better explain it myself!

Comment: There are two ways I can suppose. Both use macro-enabled workbook `.xlsm`. 1. Using UDF in formula, which you enter into cell of workbook A, the formula puts to defined cell of workbook B a value from or a reference to defined cell of workbook A. 2. You have some VBA macro in workbook A, and you need a sub, that puts to defined cell of workbook B a value from or a reference to defined cell of workbook A. What is appropriate for you?

Answer (score 1):

here I leave a starting point for what you need.

```
Public Sub CopyToDestination()
  Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
  Dim RangeValues As Range
  Set RangeValues = Selection
  wbDestination = InputBox("Insert file path/name.xlsx")
  sheetDestination = InputBox("Insert Sheet Name")
  RangeDestination = InputBox("Insert Cell Destination")
  Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(wbDestination)
  wb1.Activate
  wb1.Sheets(sheetDestination).Range(RangeDestination).Value = RangeValues.Value
  wb1.Save
  wb1.Close
End Sub
```

HOW TO USE:

1. Add this code in Excel vba module.
2. In excel, select the cells you want to copy
3. execute the macro
4. Write the full location eg."c:/test/Destination.xlsx"
5. Write the Destination Sheet name
6. Write the Location you want to paste eg. "A4" (if you select a range, you must write the range, eg. "A1:C4"
7. magic!

I repeat, it is a starting point, if you will use it every day, may have to improve.

hope it works, cheers!